# Unable to deploy cyclos

Tags: xml, jsp, tomcat, jstl, web-deployment

I'm having `http:// 500` error when trying to deploy `cyclos4.7` on `apache-tomcat-8.5.8`, can anyone help me figure out the problem???

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: The requested resource (/content/index) is not available
    org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.serveResource(DefaultServlet.java:756)
    org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:425)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:887)
    org.apache.jsp.cyclos.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:115)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I keep getting   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.cyclos.index_jsp  OR      org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Comment: Please post also a taglib import example in one of your pages, the jstl library included in your application and the servlet version declared in your web.xml

Comment: Problem solved, i hadn't configured my my Postgres Server yet and so it was generating errors in tomcat's catalina log files, when i saw it and fixed that initial error, voila!!!